# Assigning content of a R dataFrame cell based on some conditions

Tags: r

I have a R DataFrame df with the following content:

```
Serial N         year         current
   B              10            14
   B              10            16
   C              12            11
   D              40            20
   B              11            15
   C              12             9
```

I would like to add a column which compute the average current if serial number and the year are the same serial number and years.
 I would like to have something like this

```
Serial N         year         current    Average 
   B              10            14          15
   B              10            16          15
   C              12            13          12
   D              40            20          20
   B              11            15          15
   C              12            11          12
```

I wrote this

```
for (i in unique(df$Serial_N))
   {
       for (j in unique (df$year))
         {  data=subset(df,Serial_N==i & year==j)   
            df$Average<-mean(data$current)  
          }
    }
```

When I run it, I have the following error

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "Average", value = NaN) : 
replacement has 1 row, data has 0
```

What is problem? How can I fix it?

Comment: How did you get the average for D as 40?

Comment: `transform(df, Avg = ave(current, Serial_N, year))`?

Comment: Ok, so you changed the output again.  I was getting your new output.

Comment: I am sorry for the mistake. It is indeed 20 not 40

Comment: How did you get `12` as average?

Comment: @Frank I think you can close it

Comment: 12 come from 13+11/2 since there are 2 Cs with the same year as well.

Comment: In that case, the input data and expected data current column is not the same.  Please check.

Comment: The average of both currents for each serial number C and year 12 is put in each of their row.

Comment: What i meant is that in the 'current' column for expected you have 13 in place of 11 and 11 in place of 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), grouped by 'SerialN', and 'year', we get the `mean` of 'current' and assign it to a new column 'Average'.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, Average := mean(current) ,.(SerialN, year)]
```

Comment: This is what I get :could not find function "setDT"

Comment: @user3841581  Sorry, I didn't specify the library.  You have to call `library(data.table)` after installing it using `install.packages('data.table')`

Comment: I installed it and it seems to work. Thank you

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was marked as duplicate

Comment: Just by curiosity, what is I wanted the average row wise; for example if we had current 1 and current 2. and I wanted the average of the two  row wise given that they have the same serial number?

Comment: @user3841581  You can use `rowMeans` i.e. `setDT(df)[, Average := rowMeans(.SD), .SDcols= current1:current2]`

Comment: still from data.table? wow; it works like the pandas dataFrames. Thanks again

Comment: @user3841581  Or use `Reduce` i.e. `setDT(df)[,  Average := Reduce(`+`, .SD)/length(.SD), .SDcols= current1:current2]`

Comment: When I try using rowsMeans, I have the following: rowMeans(.SD) : 'x' must be numeric ? Does it not handle nan?

Comment: @user3841581  Because `.SD` selects all the columns .  If there are non-numeric columns, we have to specify the numeric columns with `.SDcols=..`

Comment: But all the values I have are numeric or they have nan. My current 1 and current 2 are all numeric or have na

Comment: @user3841581  Please check the `str(df)`  It could be that the column class is different.

Comment: when I tried the method you initially mentioned (setDT(df)[, Average := mean(current) ,.(SerialN, year)]) on another dataset, the resulting average contain only NA, even though current has numeric values. Any ideas on what is the problem?

Comment: @user3841581  It may be because there are missing values in the data.set.  Use `na.rm=TRUE` i.e. `setDT(df)[, Average := mean(current, na.rm=TRUE), .(SerialN, year)]`

Comment: It  works perfectly. Thanks a lot

Comment: just by curiousity again, what if I just wanted to apply the mean on only Serial N with value B only?

Comment: @user3841581  You may need to specify the 'i' i.e. `setDT(df)[SerialN=='B', mean(current)]`

Comment: Thank you. This cover the foundation on the usage of table. Thanks a lot